# java.io.FileNotFoundException when using tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I have an application running fine on localhost but I am having issues when It is deployed on tomcat

The code I am using to read the file is :

```
File jasperFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("reports/Header.jasper").getFile());
```

I get this error in catalina :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat9/webapps/com.peek.facture.server/WEB-INF/lib/facture.server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/reports/Header.jasper
```

What triggers me is the "!" at the end of the jar name, where does it come from?

Also I have tried to download the jar, extract it, and my Header.jasper is correctly in the resources/reports/ folder

Comment: Try /reports/Header.jasper

Comment: getting a java.lang.NullPointerException in localhost using /reports

Comment: How did you run it on "localhost"? Did you just start it from your IDE or did you build + deploy a jar or war to a local tomcat?

Comment: When it is started from my IDE it works, and I get this error when running on a tomcat

Comment: Stop using File IO for resources embedded in your jar and available from the classpath. File IO is for files. Not for embedded resources. You don't need a File. Just pass the URL to Jasper. And if it doesn't accept a URL, use getResourceAsStream() and pass the returned stream.

Comment: The getFile() method of URL *does not* return a valid file name.  Don’t use the File class at all.  Just read directly from the URL, or use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("reports/Header.jasper")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run on your local a **stand-alone physical** file `Header.jasper` exists (you can physically see it when you browse the `reports` directory).

However when you deploy to a tomcat server, that **stand-alone physical** file no longer exists. Instead, if you set-up your build correctly, when you open up your jar (`facture.server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`), there should be a directory called `reports` in it with the file `Header.jasper` within that directory.

So when your try get a resource via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...).getFile()` you are actually trying to access a **stand-alone physical** file. Instead you need to get the resource as an `InputStream` and then work with if from there...

```
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("reports/Header.jasper");
```

When working with resources, it's always better to rather access them this way. Especially if you are planning to deploy anywhere with a single artifact, because your resources should be packaged in with your artifact.